# Google Analytics event on element appear

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to call a Google Analytics event when an element with id=pricing is viewed. I cannot see a call being sent (checked via Network tab in Firebug).

My code looks as follows:

```
pricing_viewed = false;
function SendEvent() {
   if (pricing_viewed === false) {
        console.log("pricing viewed"); //this is properly shown in Console when the div with id=pricing is viewed
        ga('send', 'event', 'Conversions', 'Viewed', 'Pricing table');                
        pricing_viewed = true;
    }
}
$('#pricing').appear();
$('#pricing').on('appear', SendEvent);
```

I'm using Universal Analytics and GTM (although I'm trying to call the event directly from the code without GTM).

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have two tracking codes at the same time? From Universal and GTM?

Comment: are there any errors?

Comment: If that's your exact code then there are errors because you're missing a curly brace at the end of your `if` statement.

Comment: Hi @DiegoZoracKy - I had only DTM in place.

Comment: There were no errors, the "}" was in place. It was just missing from the code above (I added it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Philipp Walten points out you have a syntax error.

Your other/bigger problem is that GTM does not create the tracker with the default name (t0), so your send calls probably go nowhere. The solution would be to use a named tracker.

In GTM (assuming v2) you can go to your analytics tag, advanced configuration, check "set tracker name" and enter a name, e.g. "myTracker". Then change your inline code to

```
ga('myTracker.send', 'event', 'Conversions', 'Viewed', 'Pricing table');
```

That way you make sure all calls go the same tracker instance.

Better yet use your sendEvent function to push data to the dataLayer variable, set up variables in GTM and use a second Analytics tag that's configured for event tracking.

Comment: Eike, both of the solutions (adding tracker) and pushing the data to the dataLayer worked. Thank you very much!